# Im using JOptionPane and I'm not sure why its not working when I try to enter the Item Id for the first "?" it asks in my code

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane, parallel-arrays

A company manufactures 10 items. write java program to store 10 items and their prices in arrays. if a customer ordered an item, your program checks whether it is valid, if it is valid print price

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ParallelArray3 {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final int Num =10;
        int [] Item= {101, 110, 210, 220, 300, 310, 316, 355, 405, 410};
        double [] Price= {0.29, 1.23, 3.50, 0.89, 6.79, 3.12, 4.32, 3.6, 8.3, 5.4};

        String ItemId = null;
        while ((ItemId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your Item ID number: ")) != null)
        {
            boolean correct = false;
            for (int x = 0; x < Item.length; ++x)
            {
                if(ItemId.equals(Item[x]))
                {
                    JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your Item is: " + Item[x] + "\n" + "the price is: " + Price[x], JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                    correct = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(! correct)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "item ID not found, try again.", "Not found", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

expected results will show the item number and the price to it

actual result is saying every item# is invalid

Comment: Did you debug through it? Did you check whether `if(ItemId.equals(Item[x])` is ever true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are comparing a String and an Int

```
   if(ItemId.equals(Item[x]))
    {
```

Should be changed to

```
   if(Integer.parseInt(ItemId)==(Item[x]))
    {
```

final code becomes

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ParallelArray3 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
final int Num =10;
int [] Item= {101, 110, 210, 220, 300, 310, 316, 355, 405, 410};
double [] Price= {0.29, 1.23, 3.50, 0.89, 6.79, 3.12, 4.32, 3.6, 8.3, 5.4};

String ItemId = null;
while ((ItemId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your Item ID number: ")) != null)
{
    System.out.println(ItemId);
    boolean correct = false;
    for (int x = 0; x < Item.length; x++)
    {
        if(Integer.parseInt(ItemId)==(Item[x]))
        {
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Your Item is: " + Item[x] + "\n" + "the price is: " + Price[x], JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            correct = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!correct)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "item ID not found, try again.", "Not found", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

[image: see screenshot below]

Comment: @Kale_Kyle if you agree with this answer mark it(up arrow) /accept it as the correct answer